# Сравнение элемента списка с интервалом Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

Такая задача, нужно сравнить входить ли элемент из df в интервал и если входит нужно произвести некоторые подсчеты, и так с каждым элементом, в зависимости от того в какой интервал входит

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
#print(excel_file.sheet_names)
require_cols = [1]
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', usecols=require_cols)
df_max = df.iloc[df['Data'].idxmax()]
df_min = df.iloc[df['Data'].idxmin()]
my_list = df["Data"].tolist()
interval = pd.cut(np.array(my_list), 9)
print(my_list)
print(interval)
print(df_max)
print(df_min)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Еще вы забыли задать вопрос)

Comment: [3414, 3563, 3391, 3463, 3110, 2844, 3292, 3321, 3608, 2753, 2886, 3596, 3644, 4029, 4023, 4870, 5859, 6321, 5923, 5699, 5521, 5995]
[(3149.444, 3545.889], (3545.889, 3942.333], (3149.444, 3545.889], (3149.444, 3545.889], (2749.432, 3149.444], ..., (5924.556, 6321.0], (5528.111, 5924.556], (5528.111, 5924.556], (5131.667, 5528.111], (5924.556, 6321.0]]
Data    6321
Data    2753

Comment: Это то что выводит программа

Comment: Как проверить какому интервалу принадлежит элемент списка(my_list), и создать еще один массив  и заполнить его по принципу ( если 1 элемент первому интервалу, в массиве мы обозначаем его А1 если второму то А2 и так далее с каждым элементом списка(my_list)

Comment: Не надо писать комментарии, правте вопрос.